# Print out preceding lines after regex match

Tags: regex, perl, string-matching

I am writing a sort of quiz program. I am using a .txt file as a test bank, but cant figure out how to (using regex's) match each question and print out the possible answers on different lines.I originally was just going to do true false so I didnt need to match anything else and just matching "1" worked fine. Basically I just need the question on one line and the answers on others. Here is an example of a question

```
1.) some text
 a.) solution 
 b.) solution 
 c.) solution
```

code i had before:

```
while (<$test>) {

    foreach my $line (split /\n/) {

        my $match1 = "1";

            if ($line =~ /$match1/) {
                $question1 = $line;
                print "$question1\n";
                print "Answer: ";           
                $answer1 = <>;
                chomp ($answer1);
                    if ( $answer1 =~ /(^a$)/i) {
                        $score1 = 20;
                            push @score, $score1;
                    }       
            }
```

Comment: while <$test> is only going to give you a single line.

Comment: @sln, it depends on what `$/` is. If it's undefined, you slurp the file. However, you wouldn't slurp the file in a while loop. But you could have specific record-separators.

Comment: Then he won't need the while(). Unless he re-uses $test in a close/open below the split. Yes, that's true, he could use some obscure separator not named newline.

Comment: @kspaeth - There are many ways to do this. You could use the `/../ .. /../ flag stuff, or use a \G anchor or just a global flag if /^\d/ or not.

Comment: Why don't you split your question/answer file into chunks (e.g. separated by `\n\n`) so you can print a whole chunk (containing a question and the possible answers) in one go, rather than reading the file in a line at a time? Better still, why not create a nice data structure with an array of hashes containing the question, possible solutions, and the correct answer in it? e.g. `[ { question => 'Which way is up?', answers => { a => 'This way', b => 'That way', c => 'Dunno' }, correct => 'c' }, { ... }]`

Comment: I'm with @ialarmedalien on this. You should create an initial hash structure of Q & A then do the grading of tests which is another parse endeavor.

Comment: Sorry for being a noob, but how would I go about that? This is for an assignment so I need to use files and regex.

Answer (score 1):

I really couldn't get what you were getting at, so I wrote this sample program.

```
use 5.016;
use strict;
use warnings;
my ( @lines, @questions, $current_question );

sub prompt { 
    my ( $prompt ) = @_;
    print $prompt, ' ';
    STDOUT->flush;
    my $val = <>;
    return $val;
}

QUESTION:
while ( <DATA> ) { 
    if ( my ( $ans ) = m/^=(\w+)/ ) {
        INPUT: { 
            say @lines;
            last unless defined( my $answer = prompt( 'Your answer:' ));
            say '';
             my ( $response ) = $answer =~ /([a-z])\s*$/;
            if ( not $response ) { 
                $answer =~ s/\s*$//; #/
                say "Invalid response. '$answer' is not an answer!\n"; 
                redo INPUT;
            }
            if ( $response eq $ans ) { 
                say 'You are right!';
            }
            elsif ( my $ansln = $current_question->{$response} ) { 
                if ( $response eq 'q' ) { 
                    say 'Quitting...';
                    last QUESTION;
                }
                say <<"END_SAY";
You chose:\n$current_question->{$response}
The correct answer was:\n$current_question->{$ans}
END_SAY
            }
            else { 
                say "Invalid response. '$response' is not an answer!\n";
                redo INPUT;
            }
        };
        @lines = ();
        prompt( 'Press enter to continue.' );
        say '';
    }
    else { 
        if ( my ( $qn, $q ) = m/^\s*(\d+)\.\)\s+(.*\S)\s*$/ ) { 
            push @questions, $current_question = { question => $q };
        }
        else {
            my ( $l, $a ) = m/^\s+([a-z])/;
            $current_question->{$l} = ( m/(.*)/ )[0];
        }
        push @lines, $_;
    }
}

__DATA__
1.) Perl is
  a.) essential
  b.) fun
  c.) useful
=c
2.) This question is
 a.) Number two
 b.) A test to see how this format is parsed.
 c.) Unneeded
=b
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably over simplified.
It just reads in the test data and creates a structure.
You could use it to grade test takers answers.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

$/ = undef;

my $testdata = <DATA>;

my %HashTest = ();
my $hchoices;
my $hqeustion;
my $is_question = 0;

while ( $testdata =~ /(^.*)\n/mg )
{
    my $line = $1;
    $line =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
    next if ( length( $line ) == 0);

    if ( $line =~ /^(\d+)\s*\.\s*\)\s*(.*)/ )
    {
       $is_question = 1;
       $HashTest{ $1 }{'question'} = $2;
       $HashTest{ $1 }{'choices'}  = {};
       $HashTest{ $1 }{'answer'}  = 'unknown';

       $hqeustion = $HashTest{ $1 };
       $hchoices  = $HashTest{ $1 }{'choices'};
    }
    elsif ( $is_question && $line =~ /^\s*(answer)\s*:\s*([a-z])/ )
    {
        $hqeustion->{'answer'} = $2;
    }
    elsif ( $is_question && $line =~ /^\s*([a-z])\s*\.\s*\)\s*(.*)/ )
    {
        $hchoices->{ $1 } = $2;
    }
}

print "\nQ & A summary\n-------------------------\n";

for my $qnum ( keys %HashTest )
{
    print "Question $qnum:  $HashTest{$qnum}{'question'}'\n";
    my $ans_code = $HashTest{$qnum}{'answer'};
    print "Answer: ($ans_code)  $HashTest{$qnum}{'choices'}{$ans_code}\n\n";
}

print "---------------------------\n";
print Dumper(\%HashTest);


__DATA__

1.) What is the diameter of the earth?
 a.) Half the distance to the sun 
 b.) Same as the moon 
 c.) 6,000 miles
 answer: c

2.) Who is buried in Grants Tomb?
 a.) Thomas Edison 
 b.) Grant, who else 
 c.) Jimi Hendrix
 answer: b
```

Output:

```
Q & A summary
-------------------------
Question 1:  What is the diameter of the earth?'
Answer: (c)  6,000 miles

Question 2:  Who is buried in Grants Tomb?'
Answer: (b)  Grant, who else

---------------------------
$VAR1 = {
          '1' => {
                   'question' => 'What is the diameter of the earth?',
                   'answer' => 'c',
                   'choices' => {
                                  'c' => '6,000 miles',
                                  'a' => 'Half the distance to the sun',
                                  'b' => 'Same as the moon'
                                }
                 },
          '2' => {
                   'question' => 'Who is buried in Grants Tomb?',
                   'answer' => 'b',
                   'choices' => {
                                  'c' => 'Jimi Hendrix',
                                  'a' => 'Thomas Edison',
                                  'b' => 'Grant, who else'
                                }
                 }
        };
```